# ant copy folder from zip file

Tags: ant

I have a zip file with the following structure

apache-tomcat-6.0.26.zip
 apache-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/manager

I want to copy just the manager folder into another dir

I tried

```
<copy todir="${tomcat.webapp.dir}/manager/" includeEmptyDirs="true">
 <zipfileset src="${tomcat.zip.file}/" >
  <patternset>
   <include name="apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}/webapps/manager" />
  </patternset>
 </zipfileset>
</copy>
```

The output manager folder contains the following structure
apache-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/manager. I just need the manager folder and its content not its parents.

Tried changing the  to  but get an error msg that the folder is not an archieve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a patternset to restrict the files to be extracted from the zip, coupled with a mapper that strips off the leading directory name

```
<unzip src="apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}.zip" dest="${tomcat.webapp.dir}/manager">
    <patternset>
        <include name="**/webapps/manager/**"/>
    </patternset>
    <globmapper from="apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}/webapps/manager/*" to="*"/>
</unzip>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
<copy todir="${tomcat.webapp.dir}/manager/" includeEmptyDirs="true">
 <zipfileset src="${tomcat.zip.file}/" prefix="apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}/webapps" >
  <patternset>
   <include name="apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}/webapps/manager" />
  </patternset>
 </zipfileset>
</copy>
```

I intensely dislike the `<unzip>` task because when it fails, it gives no errors (the default for `<copy>` is to fail on error, which is exactly what you want in a build.)